# How to make Google SketchUp work with Intel graphics in Wine?

Tags: 10.10, wine, intel-graphics, opengl

My pc has an Intel DH57JG mainboard, I've installed wine, launching sketchup I receive error that I don't have OpenGL installed, is there a way to configure/install it? On my previous pc with an NVidia video card installing official NVidia driver resolved it. Is there is a way to do the same with the Intel card?

Running `locate libgl` on a terminal returns no results.

thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds to me like wine cannot find the required libraries.
run `locate libgl*` in a terminal and attach the output to your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've installed SketchUp 8 and had the same error.

Here's how I got it to work:

- Open a Terminal, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

  ```
  wine regedit
  ```
- Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Google → SketchUp8 → GLConfig → Display
- Change the value of HW_OK to `1` (so that it shows up as `0x00000001 (1)`)

Then start SketchUp

I hope this works for you as well :)

Comment: you are really a Ubuntu Guru!!! Thanks my proble is result!

Comment: Stefano,
        Great. A very clear and concise instruction,which worked first time.
Many thanks   Bob McM